# How can I get ordered distinct IDs with pagination?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, pagination

Let's say I have two tables: `Person` and `Address`. Both have a numeric '`id`' column, and a person record can have multiple addresses (foreign key '`Address.person_id`' which references  '`Person.id`').

I now want to

- **search** persons with criteria on both the person and it's addresses
- **sort** the result by person/address attributes, and
- return the **distinct person ids**
- using **pagination** (additional restriction on row range, calculated by page number and page size)

Getting the *non-distinct* person ids is quite simple:

```
select p.id from person p 
left join address a on a.person_id = p.id
where p.firstname is not null
order by a.city, p.lastname, p.firstname
```

But now I can't just select the `distinct(p.id)`, as I have an order, which cannot be applied unless I select the order criteria as well.

If I wrap the SQL-snippet above with `select distinct(id) from (...)`, I get the distinct `id`s, but *lose the order* (ids come in arbitrary order, probably due to hashing)

I came up with a generic but rather impractical solution which works correctly doesn't satisfy me yet (3 outer selects):

```
select id from (
    select id, rownum as r from (
        select distinct(ID), min(rownum) from (
            select p.id from person p 
            left join address a on a.person_id = p.id
            where p.firstname is not null
            order by a.city, p.lastname, p.firstname
        )
        group by (id)
        order by min(rownum)
    )
) where r>${firstrow} and r<=${lastrow}
```

*(Placeholders ${firstrow} and ${lastrow} will be replaced by values calculated from page number and page size)*

- **Is there a better way** to just get the ordered distinct IDs with
  pagination?
- I'm implementing these searches using the **Hibernate Criteria API**, can I somehow realize the outer selects as a `Projection` in Hibernate, or create my own projection implementation which does this?

Answer (score 1):

you basically want to sort the persons by their min address (not sure this makes any sense to me, but it should only make sense to you). in this case you can try

```
select person_id 
from    (
    select a.person_id , min(a.city || p.lastname || p.firstname)
    from person p left join address a 
        on (a.person_id = p.id)
    where p.firstname is not null
    group by a.person_id
    order by 2 ) 
where rownum < x
```

couple of technical notes -

- if every person has an adress lose the `left join`.
- if you'r using `group by` you dont need to specify `distinct`.

Comment: Nice idea, only the sorting won't work correctly when just comparing concatenated strings (especially when sorting dates, timestamps, numeric values, or when some sort criteria are descending).